# Es correcta esta forma de relacionar mis schemas ProductoSchema y UsuarioSchema en mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

tenga una simple duda:
Tengo 3 Schemas: **Usuario, Producto, Carrito**

**Usuario**

```
  const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const {Schema} = mongoose;

const UsuarioSchema = new Schema({
    nombre:{type:String, required:true},
    apellidos:{type:String, required:false},
    usuario:{type:String, required:false},
    email:{type:String, required:false},
    password:{type:String, required:false},
    fecha_registro:{type:String, required:false},
    carrito:{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "Carrito"}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Usuario',UsuarioSchema);
```

**Producto**:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const {Schema} = mongoose;

const ProductoSchema = new Schema({
    nombre:{type:String, required:true},
    descripcion:{type:String, require:false},
    precio:{type:String, required:false},
    fecha_lanzamiento:{type:String, required:false}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Producto',ProductoSchema);
```

**Carrito**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const CarritoSchema = new Schema({
    producto: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "Producto" },
    cantidad: {type:Number, required:true}

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Carrito', CarritoSchema);
```

Seria correcta esta implementacion para el caso que yo quiero ?: 
Que haya productos en la web y clicken los usuarios si quieres guardarlos en su carrito.

Comment: he editado mi respuesta porque has cambiado la pregunta, un saludo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes que intentar dejar de reflejar comportamientos de bases de datos relaciones en mongo pues no está pensado para esto. En mongoDB tienes comportamientos para emular la integridad referencial como las "foreing keys" que mencionas pero no siempre es recomendable llevar esta comprobación a la base de datos (lo cual es el comportamiento estándar en SQL). En el caso de mongo, aunque puedas tener integridad referencial a base de datos, mongo no está 100% diseñado para esto sino para llevar esa "lógica" de integridad referencial a tu aplicación. Teniendo esto en cuenta, vamos a ver varias opciones que tienes en tu caso.

La más recomendada, siguiendo la lógica anterior sería llevar la integridad referencial a tu aplicación. Para ello, debes añadir en tu colección de usuarios un campo que sea un array de productos de esta forma:

```
{"carrito": ["producto1", "producto2"..."producton"]}
```

Y de esta forma, los usuarios tienen asociado su lista de productos pero no sabes si ese producto está en la otra colección o no. Para ello, en tu aplicación puedes consultar la lista de productos y cotejarla con la colección de productos para mandar un error si hay algo en la lista que no pertenece a tus productos (o no mandar error pero eliminar los resultados que sean inválidos).

Hay que pensar que estos errores no tienen que ocurrir si tu base de datos está protegida contra escritura y en la inserción desde tu aplicación se comprueba que lo que se inserta pertenece a productos. Esta es la forma de trabajo natural de Mongo porque mongo se utiliza para ser rápido y poder tener datos no estructurados, con la ventaja de que los servidores de hoy en día son mucho más rápidos para hacer estas comprobaciones que los motores de bases de datos.

Si tienes el requerimiento o la necesidad de usar la integridad referencial a nivel de base de datos puedes utilizar las referencias de mongo. Añadiendo la lista de productos pero utilizando el _id del producto en lugar de tener una lista de String:

```
{productos: ["_id1", "_id2"..."_idn"]}
```

siendo _id el id de ese documento en la colección de productos, funcionando esto de forma similar a como lo haría una clave foránea en una base de datos relacional. Hay que tener en cuenta que esto no es para lo que mongo ha sido diseñado ya que afecta al rendimiento debido a que se realiza una segunda query para buscar la tabla productos (y la idea de mongo es realizar la query de la forma más rápida posible aunque saques "registros" de más ya que estos los puedes y debes filtrar desde la aplicación).

Con este segundo enfoque también ganas algo en comodidad pues una simple edición de un producto servirá para editar el producto en todos los usuarios mientras que en la primera manera, tienes que lanzar un update en usuarios cuando lo hagas en producto.

**EDIT** Porque ha cambido la pregunta:
La forma que propones de crear una colección intermedia es la forma que tienen las bases de datos relacionales de gestionar las relaciones many to many como es tu caso, en mongo esto no tiene sentido porque se pueden insertar **listas** por lo que lo correcto sería, como he comentado más arriba, insertar la lista de productos en cada documento de usuarios. En mongo se debe tratar siempre de tener la menor cantidad de colecciones posibles pues se ha diseñado para hacer queries de la forma más rápida posible y es mucho más eficiente cogiendo muchos registros de una sola colección que atacando a varias.

Comment: La cambie porque por la respuesta anterior y pense que estaba mal y tenia que cambiar ara ser mas entendible

Comment: A ver si me queda claro de una vez el tema de los schemas. Como dices , la mejor opcion es meter a usuarios un array de productos. Perfecto borro la tabla carrito ya que estoy intentando tratar a una bd no relacional como si relacional. Lo cual es un error. Perfecto. Pero si quiero saber cuantas compras ha hecho de x producto que tendria que sumarlo a lo bruto ?. U otra cosa que no se contempla es como puedo definir la cantidad de X producto que estoy comprando. Porque si pongo un array de prodcutos en usuario, como podria contabilizar que cantidad de X prdcuto tiene guardado. No podria sabe.

Comment: si quieres entra en el chat de stackoverflow y lo comentamos que es más de una pregunta, saludos!

Comment: perfecto, si me pones el link de n chat que aun no se como entrar jeje